# Positioning text and images within a td cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, positioning

I have three tables on my page, each with one row, and three data cells inside.

My issue is, when adding text to a cell, it is increasing the height of the table though I have already defined a height. My second issue is positioning the pictures in the final (3rd) data cells to be in the middle.

```css
#snake {
  background-color: #c4df9b;
}
#bat {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#monkey {
  background-color: #c69c6d;
}
#monkeygraphic {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.animalcontainer {
  width: 682px;
  height: 200px;
}
.animalcontainer td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 227px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-left">
  <table id="snake" class="animalcontainer">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="images/snakegraphic.png" alt="Snake Graphic" title="Snake Graphic" width="155" height="196">
      </td>
      <td>sad</td>
      <td id="snakepic">
        <img src="images/snake.jpg" alt="Snake" title="Snake" width="152" height="152">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="bat" class="animalcontainer">
    <tr>
      <td id="batgraphic">
        <img src="images/batgraphic.png" alt="Bat Graphic" title="Bat Graphic" width="198" height="98">
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>sad</h1>
      </td>
      <td id="batpic">
        <img src="images/bat.jpg" alt="Bat" title="Bat" width="152" height="150">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="monkey" class="animalcontainer">
    <tr>
      <td id="monkeygraphic">
        <img src="images/monkeygraphic.png" alt="Monkey Graphic" title="Monkey Graphic" width="207" height="185">
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>sad</h1>
      </td>
      <td id="monkeypic">
        <img src="images/monkey.jpg" alt="Monkey" title="Monkey" width="152" height="150">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, i've just learnt the vertical-align css "thing" which seems to have sorted my issue.

Thanks to anybody who read the question though.

(Fix: giving my middle td cells a class, and adding vertical-align: top; to the css)